# ledger in org-babel blocks uses incorrect path data in Windows 10

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to include a ledger data file from an org-babel block. I am using Windows10 and the SciMax emacs distribution.

```
#+begin_src ledger :cmdline bal :results output :exports results
!include d:/Ledger/RLbook.dat
#+end_src
#+RESULTS  (this is all that appears regardless of the header options)
```

If I call the file using `!include RLbook.dat` in the org-block (see below), the block produces the word `#+RESULTS` but no actual numbers regardless of the header options. Using or excluding `!` makes no difference.

My config file call ledgers `(ledger . t)` as required. The data in the external file produces results if I copy it directly into the org-babel block or if used directly in ledger-mode so I know the data is formatted properly.

I discovered that that although I specify this path in the block `d:/Ledger/RLbook.ledger`, its being interpreted as `c:/Users\Arjay\AppData\Local\Temp\babel-16324iS0\d:/Ledger\RLbook.ledger` according to my Messages buffer. I cannot figure out how this extra path data is being added or how to prevent it.

How can I avoid or correct the incorrect path data being added to the path name?

Note: I rebuilt the ledger executable using the instructions from https://gist.github.com/ngleb/944346a67960776371aab74149edf38c. This fixed a problem with ledger not understanding paths when used from the cmd line in a terminal window. It did not fix this problem.

Comment: can You edit an example of your transaction (formatted exactly the way it is typed in your code block) into your question? and also, do you have ledger installed and `(ledger . t)` included in the `org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages` command in your .emacs?

Comment: I have updated and refined  my question based on more testing. Please review.

Comment: I'm assuming that `org-babel` makes a mistake and interprets the path as relative. I haven't used Emacs on Windows in ages, so I don't remember what's the way to define absolute paths with a partition, and IIRC it depends on what kind of build you're using (native one built with mingw, cygwin or any other option).

Answer (score 0):

You should add `:noweb yes` just after `#+begin_src ledger`. Then at least some form of include should work. Under my Linux system absolute file names work, relative paths from $HOME (i.e., `~/mydir/filename`) work, but link to current directory (i.e., `./filename`) does not work. Don't know about the Windows world, but in any case the `:noweb yes`-part is essential for inclusion to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you.  I couldn't fix it, but came up with this workaround.

Put the ledger code in `d:/Ledger/RLbook.dat` into a named org source block and save the file as `RLbook.org`:

```
This entire block here is stored in a file called =RLbook.org=, including this sentence!

#+name: include
#+begin_src ledger :noweb yes
;; put your ledger code here
;; the next line is actually valid ledger code!
eval print ("Hello, world!")
#+end_src
```

Call `(org-babel-lob-ingest "C:/path/to/RLbook.org")`.  This reads in the named source block from the given file.  Make sure that you either have forward slashes or escape the backslash (i.e. `\\`).

You can now reference the named source block in your main org file.

```
This is my main.org file!

#+begin_src ledger :noweb yes
<<include>>
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello, world!
```

Put the `org-babel-lob-ingest` call somewhere in your `init.el`.  Or, if you want to keep everything in your `main.org` file, you could [use the `:eval` file variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356472/emacs-per-file-customization/4356877#4356877):

```
;; -*- eval: (org-babel-lob-ingest "C:/path/to/include.org") -*-
This is my main.org file!

#+begin_src ledger :noweb yes
<<include>>
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello, world!
```